# peekRecord() is not working but peekAll() is working

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

My backend always responds with all available data and it took a considerably amount of time. So I'm reloading store periodically and I plan to use peekAll() and peekRecord().

My code is:

```
model: function() {
  return Ember.RSVP.hash({
    'clusters': this.store.peekAll('cluster'),
    'single': this.store.peekRecord('cluster', 'cluster::My')
});
```

When code is executed, at first I can see that both of these items do not contain content. After few seconds data are loaded to store and I can see content 'clusters' on template as expected. But 'single' is still completely without content ({{model.single}} does not return nothing in template). But when I have a button with action:

```
alert(this.store.peekRecord('cluster', 'cluster::My'));
```

I can see that the record was found. Records are also available via Ember Inspector. What am I doing wrong that only peekAll() works in model for me.

Comment: When are you loading the record `cluster::My` into the store?  If it's happening asynchronously or after your `peekRecord` it won't return, whereas `peekAll` is an active collection that updates as the store populates.

Comment: It is happening asynchronously. I thought that these methods uses same mechanism for obtaining information with some filtering on peekRecord side. Your explanation makes sense, so thanks for it. What is the right way, to have information in model obtained from same time?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The semantics of both methods are:

- `store.peekAll` returns a live array that is updated as the store is updated.
- `store.peekRecord` returns the corresponding object in the current cache, or `null`, and it does not update.

So the behaviour you're observing is the expected one. If you want to use the `peek` methods, my advise is to make sure that the initial request has finished loading before fetching any data from the store.

Comment: Thanks. In order to have peekRecord that is updated like peekRecord, it is possible to use """this.store.filter('cluster', (item) => { return item.id === 'cluster::My'}), """.